# How to jquery label/Radio button is enable when new page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

My codeigniter site has parameter males and females as follows. `route.php` is done.

```
http://localhost/males
http://localhost/female
```

`view.php` is here with two labels.

```
<li>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default gender-label" id="lbl-female">
       <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off">
           <span>Females</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default gender-label" id="lbl-male">
     <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">
         <span>Males</span>
      </label>
  </div></li>
```

When the page is loaded `http://localhost` two labels are appear. When the user click female it will redirect to the `http://localhost/females`. But new page female-label is not selected. new page side bar has same UI. how to make as selected radio/label when it cleck and redirect to new page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var genderSelect = "";
    $("#lbl-female").click(function () { 
        genderSelect = 'females';
        window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + genderSelect; 
    });
    $("#lbl-male").click(function () { 
        genderSelect = 'males';      
        window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + genderSelect;    
    }); }); </script>
```

Comment: What is the problem? I don't understand your question.

Comment: can you be specifc with your requirement ?

Comment: is `http://localhost/males` and `http://localhost/females` are different application projects? or are they on the same codeigniter application?

Comment: please see the updates

Comment: you need to get the parameter passed in the controller and pass this parameter to the view and check against the radio button, Example: `<input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" <?php if($parameter == 'male') { echo "selected"; }>`

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to use activate a particular radio button on aany of the page load, is quite getting the request uri

in ur Js , you use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   //use php to check here or js to check
     <?php 
      if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='male'){;
      ?>
         $("#option1").attr('checked',false);
         $("#option2").attr('checked',true);
       <?php }else{ ?>
         $("#option1").attr('checked',true);
         $("#option2").attr('checked',false);

       <?php }?>

    var genderSelect = "";
    $("#lbl-female").click(function () { 
        genderSelect = 'females';
        window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + genderSelect; 
    });
    $("#lbl-male").click(function () { 
        genderSelect = 'males';      
        window.location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + genderSelect;    
    }); }); </script>
```

The php at the top should run and do any of the jquery as the page loads. I hope it help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on page load -

```
if(location.href.indexOf("males") >= 0) {
    $("#lbl-male").find("radio").attr("selected", "selected");
} else if (location.href.indexOf("females") >= 0) {
   $("#lbl-female").find("radio").attr("selected", "selected");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding correct, you want to have radio box pre selected based on which radio was clicked on last time( before redirect), you will have to persist this selected value and based on the value you can just set the radio.

Assuming female radio box was clicked.

```
var female_radio = $('#lbl-female');
if( femaleRadioClicked === true)
female_radio.prop('checked', true);
```